# applying list.map to two parallel lists in python

Tags: python, ironpython

I have two parallel nested lists of lists. They will always be matching in length and sub-length. For example:

```
_list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]]
_list2 = [[a,b,c],[a,b],[a,b,c,d]]
```

Now the above structure is not guaranteed. It's possible that i will get a flat list or even deeper nested lists. For that purpose if i wanted to apply a definition to each element in that list i was using list.map and recursion like so:

```
def ProcessList(_func, _list):
    return map( lambda x: ProcessList(_func, x) if type(x)==list else _func(x), _list )
```

This way I can apply a single definition to unspecified nested list. How can i do the same but two lists in parallel? I want to apply a definition that will take an element from `_list1` and for a matching element in `_list2` it will execute a definition. For example:

```
def DoSomething(i,j);
    return str(i) + str(j)
```

So if i was to apply this definition to the two lists in parallel it would return this:

```
_newList = [[1a,2b,3c],[1a,2b],[1a,2b,3c,4d]]
```

Again, the whole point is to be able to operate on unspecified lists and nested lists.

Comment: When you say - *matching element in _list2* - you mean same index elements from list2 ?

Comment: correct. same index elements

Comment: And would all sizes of the multiple lists be same? I mean if a particular list is of size - 3 x 3 (or some other irregular size) , would all other lists have same size?

Comment: The two parallel lists will always have the same and matching structure (size)

Comment: I presume you are using python2? Also you say the nesting can be arbitrary   ? What happens for `_list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]];_list2 = [["a","b","c"],["a",["b"]],["a","b","c","d"]]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I said that the nesting can be arbitrary but ALWAYS MATCHING between _list1 and _list2

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it wouldn't happen. Like I said the two lists are always matching for me so for ```_list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,[2]],[1,2,3,4]]``` the second list would be: ```_list2 = [[a,b,c],[a,[b]],[a,b,c,d]]```. Both lists are generated from the same set of element properties so what I am getting back is always the same length nested lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
>>> def ProcessList(_func, *lists):
...     return map( lambda *xs: ProcessList(_func, *xs) if all(type(x) is list for x in xs) else _func(*xs), *lists )
... 
>>> def DoSomething(*args):
...     return ''.join(map(str, args))
... 
>>> _list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]]
>>> _list2 = [['a','b','c'],['a','b'],['a','b','c','d']]
>>> 
>>> print (ProcessList(DoSomething, _list1, _list2))
[['1a', '2b', '3c'], ['1a', '2b'], ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']]
```

Comment: Dan D. Outstanding! Works just fine. Thank you,

Comment: Do you mind explaining a little bit what the ```*args``` is doing? I am relatively new to Python and this is first time I am seeing it applied. Does it mean that there could be any number of arguments used in that definition?

Comment: Yes. When in a definition the splat packs all of the positional arguments into a tuple. When used in a call the splat unpacks a sequence as positional arguments. The double splat not used here does the same for keyword arguments.

Comment: This sounds great. I like this method a lot. Thanks!

Comment: This: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131403/what-is-the-name-of-in-python has a really good explanation on what ```*args``` and ```**kwargs``` do and mean.